# Class cast error when setting Jenkins build status to 'UNSTABLE'

Tags: jenkins, build, status, jenkins-groovy

I've read in several places that it's possible to set the status of a jenkins build to the desired value (e.g. UNSTABLE) by calling `build.status = 'UNSTABLE'`. I.e. a string is used as the value; the string is converted to the correct type by the groovy magics.

I have a seed job and would like to set the status of the current build to UNSTABLE if certain conditions are met. To do this, I've written the following code:

```
// seedJob is an object of type hudson.model.FreeStyleProject
seedJob.lastBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
```

But when this code gets executed I get the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'UNSTABLE' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'hudson.model.Result'
```

Could anyone tell me why the error happens?

Thank you!

Just for the reference here is the top of the stack trace:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'UNSTABLE' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'hudson.model.Result'
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:405)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:319)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:232)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2715)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3770)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:484)
```

Comment: Maybe because you are trying to modify a previous build and not the current one. Please try : seedJob.currentBuild.result = "UNSTABLE"

Comment: But there is no such property `currentBuild`. Besides, I've checked the build number, and it was the one I wanted to set the status for, i.e. the one currently running.

Comment: Besides, the property and its type has been detected, just the value could not be converted. But it should according to what I've read an the net.